# How to properly configure and connect to SOCKS proxy

Tags: macos, networking, ssh, dns, proxy

At office we've got certain network traffic restrictions in place forcing me to look for other options. What I intend to configure is a SOCKS server running on Snow Leopard OSX, forwarded through the router available externally via dns alias, so I can connect over WAN if needed.

I have tried to create the server using the ssh -D port# user@externalhost

Afterwards, i tried to configure firefox to use the socks on 1080 and the external dns alias.

Any guideance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html with what you are attempting to do.

I'd suggest SSH tunneling as it is generally easier.